# adding a loading image or div to a function

Tags: javascript, php

How can I add a loading image or div to this function?

the week1.php file is a table that is being filled with data from an external page using file_get_contents.

Sometimes it may take a few seconds before the table is displayed without anything changing on the page so I would like to add a loading bar/image/div with text letting the user know it is loading.

Thank you

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function loadweek1() {
        $(function() {
            $('#DisplayDiv').load('schedule_tuesday/week1.php');
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: you cannot have jQuery document-ready within a function.

Comment: Darn, so no way around it? Maybe that's why I keep hitting a dead end...

Comment: you need to move it outside of that function - and call functions from there... else your code will never know when to run. this hint combined with the duplicate question should at least get you started.